# Повторное создание фрагмента внутри фрагмента

Tags: android, android-fragment, android-viewpager

Доброго времени суток! Использую внутри фрагмента[1] элемент ViewPager, который сам внутри содержит еще два фрагмента-вкладки. При первом запуске все отлично отображается и работает. 
Приложение не выключаю, запускаю еще раз создание фрагмента [1] с ViewPager. Этот фрагмент создается, а для фрагментов внутри метод OnCreateView не вызывается и они остаются незаполненными.

вызов фрагмента [1] с ViewPager:
`this.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_container, new CallsAndSmsInformationFragment()).commit();`

Фрагмент [1]:
public class CallsAndSmsInformationFragment extends Fragment {

```
View view;
private Toolbar toolbar;
private TabLayout tabLayout;
private ViewPager viewPager;
CallsFragment cfragment = new CallsFragment();
SmsFragment sfragment = new SmsFragment();
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_callsandsms_information,null);

    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    toolbar = (Toolbar) view.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

    viewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    setupViewPager(viewPager);

    tabLayout = (TabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    return view;
}


@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    cfragment.onDestroy();
    sfragment.onDestroy();
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public void onDestroyView() {

    super.onDestroyView();
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {

    super.onDetach();
}


private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(cfragment, "Звонки");
    adapter.addFragment(sfragment, "SMS");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}

class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override

    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
       // return null;
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }
}


@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    menu.clear();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.action_bar_fragment_share, menu);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    return true;
}
```

}`

Буду рад любым подсказкам по этому поводу!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в использовании FragmentPagerAdapter. Он хранит все view и не удаляет их.
Нужно использовать FragmentStatePagerAdapter.